# Get Rollup static path for json5 file like react-create-app does it

Tags: rollupjs

I have created an app using `react-create-app`. When I import a `.json5` file, it treats it as a static file, copies it to `build/dist` folder, and returns its relative path:

```
import foo from './some-file.json5'

console.log(foo); // logs: /static/media/some-file.hash.json5
```

Then I can easily fetch this file when I serve my app.

**How I can to the same thing using `rollup` and its plugins?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote my own plugin for this, enjoy:

```js
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";

export default function copyAndExportPath() {
  return {
    name: "copy-and-export-path",
    resolveId(source, importer) {
      if (source.endsWith(".json5")) {
        const absolutePath = path.resolve(path.dirname(importer), source);

        return absolutePath;
      }
    },

    load(id, importer) {
      if (id.endsWith(".json5")) {
        const [base, dest] = id.split("src");
        const absolutePathDest = path.join(base, "dist", dest);

        const destDir = path.dirname(absolutePathDest);

        if (!fs.existsSync(destDir)) {
          fs.mkdirSync(destDir, { recursive: true }, (error) => {
            if (error) {
              throw error;
            }
          });
        }

        if (fs.existsSync(destDir)) {
          fs.copyFileSync(id, absolutePathDest);
        }

        return `export default ".${dest}"`;
      }
      return null;
    },
  };
}
```